# Bounded Linear Operator and Strong operator convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $T_n\colon \ell_\infty \longrightarrow \ell_\infty$ be a linear operator defined by
\begin{equation*}
   T_n(x_1,x_2,\dots)  = (0,0,0,\dots,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots) 
  \end{equation*}
Is $T_n$ strongly operator convergent?

My attempt: Pick a certain $x$ and show that $T_n(x)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy. To this end,

Let $x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n$, then $\Vert T_n(x)-T_m(x)\Vert = 1$, for $n>m$, Therefore $T_n(x)$ is not Cauchy. Hence $T_n(x)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent. Thus $T_n$ is not strongly operator convergent.

Comment: I'd agree. Looks good to me

Comment: Yep. Looks good.

Comment: I was pretty convinced too. **Many Thanks.**

Comment: If you replace $\ell^\infty $ with $c_0$, the subspace of sequences convergent to $0,$ then you gain strong operator convergence.